# prevent multiple http request rxjs on route

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to validate session on every changing route, therefore I subscribe on route like this

```js
this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
      if (ev instanceof NavigationStart) {
           this.checkSession();
      }
});
```

but this always make duplicate http request, How to prevent duplicate request Http when previous request not completed

Comment: Why you don't use `Angular Guard` to handle checking the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a property in route that is not changing then you should try this,
[distinctuntilchanged](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged)

```js
this.router.events
  // custom compare for url
  .pipe(
    filter(ev => ev instanceof NavigationStart),
    distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev.url !== curr.url))
  .subscribe((ev) => {
    this.checkSession();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `switchMap`.

```js
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(ev => ev instanceof NavigationStart)
  switchMap(() => this.checkSession()) // checkSession should return an observable
).subscribe();
```

Inside checkSession, Instead of subscribing, return the API.